# Webkit animation of toolbar

Tags: javascript

I am planning to prepare a toolbar which is opened after clicking a button. It is opening with a right to left animation. While opening, it works but while closing it doesn't. How can I fix it? I use materialize.js framework.

Here is my css code:

```
<style>
.toolbar{
  width: 100%;       
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left .3s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: slide-left .3s ease-in;
}
.toolbar2{
  background:red;
  display:block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-left .3s ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-left {
  0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }   
  100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-left {
  0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }   
  100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
  100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }   
  0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
  100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }   
  0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
li{
  display:block;
}

</style>
```

and this is the body of the code:

```
<body>
<li ><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id='button' style="top:0px; right:0px; float:right">button</a>
<div  class = "toolbar" id ="toolbar">
  <ul class="tabs" style="top:-40px">
    <li class="tab col s12 l2"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s12 l2">
      <a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab col s12 l2 disabled">
      <a class=active>Disabled Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab col s12 l2"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('button');
  const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
  button.onclick = function(){
    if(toolbar.classList.contains('toolbar')){
      toolbar.classList.remove('toolbar');
      toolbar.classList.toggle('toolbar2');
    }
    else{
      toolbar.classList.remove('toolbar2');
      toolbar.classList.toggle('toolbar');
    }
  };


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I want it to close with animation like disappering through the right way while I click on the button again.

Comment: It doesn’t work in that direction, because your `toolbar` class sets `display: none` - which makes the element disappear instantly.

Comment: I tried the other displays too but it did not work...

Comment: You also have the opacity “backwards” in your `slide-right` keyframes.

Comment: This should not use two different sets of keyframes in the first place, if you just want the one to be the exact opposite of the other. Use one keyframe, and combine it with `animation-direction`.

Comment: is it like deleting "slide-right" keyframes and adding animation-direction to toolbar class ?